# Unable to connect to my Aurora PostgreSQL server via pgadmin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have created a VPC and Aurora PostgreSQL deployed it using CDK, public accessibility has been enabled in the RDS and it is in the Isolated Subnet, when I try to connect it using pgAdmin, it gives a timeout error, even I have changed the Security Group Inbound to Allow All ip's.

Comment: What "Isolated Subnet" is?

Comment: An isolated subnet is one that cannot reach the internet either through an IGW or with NAT.

Comment: So how do you expect to connect to it? Are you using VPN?

Comment: Now I have changed the RDS subnets to a private subnet, still I am unable to connect to it